Firebase storage mp3 does not load on safari for ios
No matter what I do, I can not get an audio file from Firebase storage to play on the safari browser for ios. I have read questions and answers from 12 years ago that tell me to write the mimeType in the metadata when I upload the file. I have done this. I have made the read public for my bucket. I went on all questions and answers on stackoverflow to debug it. I was not able to find an answer. On desktop browsers, it works fine. On iOs, whatever I do I can not listen to it (except for using a static path in my Next js public folder.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Audio Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Audio Controls Demo</h1>

    <h2>Control - local file but works with Next js</h2>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="/static/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

    <h2>Normal link with token</h2>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-audio-guide.appspot.com/o/museums%2FmuseumUrl%2Fa5876591-f645-46a1-8bca-2d605116d58e.mp3?alt=media&token=abb9080b-c5c2-464d-a589-ff3a81d835cf" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

    <h2>Normal link without token</h2>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-audio-guide.appspot.com/o/museums%2FmuseumUrl%2Fa5876591-f645-46a1-8bca-2d605116d58e.mp3?alt=media" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

    <h2>Link with no preload</h2>
    <audio controls preload="none">
        <source src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-audio-guide.appspot.com/o/museums%2FmuseumUrl%2Fa5876591-f645-46a1-8bca-2d605116d58e.mp3?alt=media&token=abb9080b-c5c2-464d-a589-ff3a81d835cf" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

    <h2>Link with metadata preload</h2>
    <audio controls preload="metadata">
        <source src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-audio-guide.appspot.com/o/museums%2FmuseumUrl%2Fa5876591-f645-46a1-8bca-2d605116d58e.mp3?alt=media&token=abb9080b-c5c2-464d-a589-ff3a81d835cf" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

    <h2>Link with auto preload</h2>
    <audio controls preload="auto">
        <source src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-audio-guide.appspot.com/o/museums%2FmuseumUrl%2Fa5876591-f645-46a1-8bca-2d605116d58e.mp3?alt=media&token=abb9080b-c5c2-464d-a589-ff3a81d835cf" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

    <h2>Link without type</h2>
    <audio controls preload="auto">
        <source src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-audio-guide.appspot.com/o/museums%2FmuseumUrl%2Fa5876591-f645-46a1-8bca-2d605116d58e.mp3?alt=media&token=abb9080b-c5c2-464d-a589-ff3a81d835cf" />
    </audio>

</body>
</html>

I uploaded the html here for your convenience:
mp3-ios-safari.tiiny.site
I expected the audio file to work with no problems as it did on my desktop browser.

I solved the problem. Someone told me that they can see the links. Upon further inspection on other people's iPhone, I figured that the problem is only in my safari. I had an extension "Firefox Focus" turned on, that for some reason blocked my download.
